# Replace second or more instances of duplicates with null

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have the following data with duplicates which I wish to identify. I do not wish to remove these so unique value only won't work. I want to be able to identify them but just saying null.

[image]

I have attempted to self-reference the code but end up just duplicating the original result.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Changed Type"),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"Column1"}, #"Removed Duplicates", {"Column1"}, "Removed Duplicates", JoinKind.LeftOuter)
in
    #"Merged Queries"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `List.Generate` to generate a list with your requirements.  And then you can either replace the first column or add the list as a second column.

This needs to be done in the Advanced Editor.
*Please note there is a difference between the text string "null" and the power query `null` value.  Based on your example screenshot, I assumed you wanted the "null" text string.  If you prefer the `null` value, remove the surrounding quotes in the code*

***M Code***

```
let

//Change next line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table13"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

//change 2nd and later duplicates to null
    dupsNull = List.Generate(
        ()=>[v=#"Changed Type"[Column1]{0}, idx=0],
        each [idx]<Table.RowCount(#"Changed Type"),
        each [v=if List.PositionOf(#"Changed Type"[Column1],#"Changed Type"[Column1]{[idx]+1},Occurrence.First) = [idx]+1
                    then #"Changed Type"[Column1]{[idx]+1} else "null", idx=[idx]+1],
        each [v]),

//either add as a column or replace the first column
    #"add de-duped" = Table.FromColumns(
            Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") & {dupsNull},
            type table[Column1=text, Column2=text])
in
    #"add de-duped"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, yes was being a bit lazy. `null` is the actual value rather than the string.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I used your solution, and it works. You mentioned in your answer: “either add as a column or replace the first column”, but the code adds a column. What would be the change to make to update the existing column? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidLeal you could use the same algorithm but with the Table.TransformColumn method. I will post a modification later today.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks. Finally I found another way to do it. I posted it as an additional answer to the question. In M Query there are multiple ways to do the same. I added also the general case of more than one column to be replaced

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way. First, add an index column. Then add another column using List.PositionOf to get the row of the first occurrence of each value in the column. Then add one last column to compare the index and List.PositionOf, to determine which row entries should be null.

```
Let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each List.PositionOf(#"Added Index"[Column1],[Column1])),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each if [Index] = [Custom] then [Column1] else null)
in
    #"Added Custom1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution that doesn't require to add a new column. It returns the same column just with duplicated values replaced with `"null"`:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TB_INPUT"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    removeDups = (lst as list) =>
        List.Accumulate(lst, {}, (x, y) => x & {if List.Contains(x, y) then "null" else y}),
    replacedValues = removeDups(Table.Column(#"Changed Type", "Column1")),
   #"replaced Values" = Table.FromList(replacedValues, null, type table[Column1 = Text.Type ])
in
     #"replaced Values"
```

it uses a `List.Accumulate` function to simplify the process to generate the corresponding list with the specified requirements.

The output will be the following in Power Query:
[image: output in Power Query]

and in Excel:

[image: Excel output]

If you want an empty cell instead of `"null"` token, then in the function `removeDups` replace `"null"` with `null`.

If you want to consider a **more general case**, lets say you have more than one column in the input *Excel Table* and you want to replace duplicated values in more than one column at the same time.

Let's say we have the following input in Excel:
[image: excel input table for the general case]

The following code can be used to replace duplicates in `Column1` and `Column2`:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TB_GralCase"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", Int64.Type}}),
    listOfColumns = {"Column1", "Column2"},
    remainingColumns = List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"), listOfColumns),
    removeDups = (lst as list) =>
        List.Accumulate(lst, {}, (x, y) => x & {if List.Contains(x, y) then "null" else y}),
    replacedValues = List.Transform(listOfColumns, each removeDups(Table.Column( #"Changed Type", _))),
    #"replaced values" = Table.FromColumns(
        replacedValues & Table.ToColumns(Table.SelectColumns( #"Changed Type", remainingColumns)),
        listOfColumns & remainingColumns
    )
in
     #"replaced values"
```

In `listOfColumns` variable, you define the list of columns you want to replace duplicates.

The the output in Power Query will be:
[image: sample output in Power Query for the general case]