# How to lookup data across different sheets by given id and aggregate the results into single cell in O365 Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-365

I have a spreadsheet with multiple sheets that each contain data I need to lookup and aggregate.

The current data structure and formats are as following:

**SheetA** (Master Sheet):

| Id | (misc) | Components | ...other non relevant columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

And the secondary sheets (**SheetB**, **SheetC**..., let's represent them as **SheetX**) with the same format:

| RefId | Id | Component | ...other non relevant columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Where **RefId** represents a value of **Id** column from the master sheet.

The goal is to populate the **Components** column from the master sheet (**SheetA**) with the information from secondary sheets (**SheetX**). Considering the following rules:

1. The content of **Components** for a given `Id` value will the be the value of Component from any secondary sheet, where **RefId** column value is the same. If there is more than value, then it concatenates all the component information delimited by comma (`,`).
2. If the Components value in the master sheet is not empty, then the content of the search by `Id` will be appended delimited by comma (`,`).
3. The sheet names can be provided as a list or just refer in the formula to each sheet name.

Lets say if we have the following input information:

Master **Sheet A**:

| Id | (misc) | Components | ...other non relevant columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 |  | xxxx |  |
| A2 |  |  |  |
| A3 |  |  |  |

**Sheet B**:

| RefId | Id | Component | ...other non relevant columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | B1Comp |  |
| A2 | B1 | B2Comp |  |
| A3 | B3 | B3Comp |  |

and

**Sheet C**:

| RefId | Id | Component | ...other non relevant columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A2 | C1 | C1Comp |  |
| A2 | C2 | C2Comp |  |

The expected result will be in the Consolidated Sheet:

| Id | (misc) | Components | ...other non relevant columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 |  | xxxx,B1Comp |  |
| A2 |  | B2Comp,C1Comp,C2Comp |  |
| A3 |  | B3Comp |  |

**Note**: Please don't consider any string pattern, they are just some string representation.

Currently I'm using the above mentioned `VLOOKUP` formulas, but they break when a sheet has multiple entries for a given `Id`.

Comment: All that text is a bit hard to follow. Can you please edit your question, post a screenshot of the latest version of the expanded table and explain what you want to see as the result? What is the input? What is the output? What is the logic? Edit your question and post a comment when you've done that.

Comment: Stripped down the question, even though I don't really see the difference and without the context it's probably more difficult to make sense of why the tables are set up the way they are. And I don't understand what you mean with "post a screenshot of the expanded table". There is no such table, I have over half a dozen tables in just as many different worksheets. Could you please clarify?

Comment: How about not using Vlookup at all, but using Power Query to merge the data you need?

Comment: @Aldoro what is the expected output in `SheetA` in the case of `SheetC`, when the same `ID` appears more than one? Now with your current solution you are getting `#N/A`, but what is the expected result?

Comment: What version of excel?  This gets profoundly easier with O365 and profoundly harder without.

Comment: @DavidLeal: In case of multiple results all `ID`s should be included in the cell/string: `B::Lorem::Ipsum, C::Dolor::Sit::Amet, C::Imups::39`

Comment: @Max: I'm using O365. Sorry for not including that, wasn't aware it would make such a big difference. I edited the question to include that information now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try with Power Query(PQ), your question is related to typical ETL operations and PQ is more suitable than using excel functions.

To easy differentiate the sheets, I am going to consider the **Master** Sheet, where we want the information consolidated and the secondary sheets, which are the input sheets to consolidate the information in the **Master**.

Since all the secondary sheets (**SheetA**, **SheetB**...) have the same structure, we can merge them.

This is the PQ command to generate **AllSheets** query as output:

```
=Table.Combine({TB_ShA, TB_ShB, TB_ShC})
```

When a connection is created from a range, PQ creates an Excel Table. I named them as: `TB_ShA`,...`TB_ShC`, for each corresponding sheet. On each table I have the following data for testing purpose (secondary sheets plus the **Master** Table). The **Master** table at the end will be updated with the consolidated components.

You can add as many sheets as you need in the previous formula to consolidate the component information. The rest of the process described here remains the same.

[image: sample input data]

Now lets explain the main steps in PQ:

Load the Master table (`TB_Master`):

[image: load master table]

Next rename the **Components** column from the master table to **Master Component**:

```
= Table.RenameColumns(Source,{{"Components", "Master Component"}})
```

Next we do a merge queries (*Home-> Merge Queries*), with the **Master** table and **AllSheets** (all secondary tables), linking **Id** and **RefId** from each tables.

```
= Table.NestedJoin(#"Renamed MasterComponent", {"Id"}, AllSheets, 
 {"RefId"}, "AllSheets", JoinKind.LeftOuter)
```

[image: Merged Queries]

and expand the Table information (just click on the top right icon of the table), here is the corresponding command:

```
= Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "AllSheets", 
  {"Component"}, {"AllSheets.Component"})
```

[image: Expanded All Sheets]

We need to change the type of **Master Component** column to `text` because later we are going to do some text operations and it is required:

```
= Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded AllSheets",
  {{"Master Component", type text}})
```

Now if we try to concatenate **Master Component** column with **AllSheets.Component** column, it works BUT, we are going to have duplication of **Master Component** values when we merge the information by unique values of the **ID** column. For example as it is now, if we merge the first two rows that belong to `M1`we will get the following:

```
xxxx,A1Comp,xxxx,BiComp
```

so we need to remove the repetition of **Master Component** column. In order to do that I used the solution from @RonRosenfeld from this question: [Replace second or more instances of duplicates with null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73004618/replace-second-or-more-instances-of-duplicates-with-null).

It requires two steps: *dupsNull* and add *de-duped*. The first one creates a temporary list with duplicated replaced with `null`, The second just adds the list created as a new column:

[image: add de-dupped]

**Note**: I am assuming the pre-populated **Components** values from the input **Master Sheet** are unique, if that is not the case, it needs to be adjusted to avoid repetition *only* per **Id** value from this sheet.

Next we remove unnecessary columns:

```
= Table.RemoveColumns(#"add de-duped",{"Master Component"})
```

and now  we are ready to concatenate both columns:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Components", 
  each Text.Combine({[Master Component.unique],
  Text.From([AllSheets.Component])},","))
```

Removing **Master Component** column:

```
= Table.RemoveColumns(#"add de-duped",{"Master Component"})
```

and this is the result:

[image: Result of Removed Component]

Finally we need to group the rows by **Id**. *Home->Group By* allows to group but it doesn't provide the function we need to concatenate the values. I took the idea from here: [Combining Rows based on the ID of that table](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/Combining-Rows-based-on-the-ID-of-that-table/m-p/1487719#M68251) to change the script and replace the `Max` function for example by `Text.Combine` and here is the final result in PQ:

[image: Grouped Rows step]

The rest is just  *Close & Load* the result in an new Sheet that is named **MasterUpdated**:

[image: MasterUpdated output]

Here is the entire PQ M script:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TB_Master"]}[Content],
    #"Renamed MasterComponent" = Table.RenameColumns(Source,{{"Components", "Master Component"}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Renamed MasterComponent", {"Id"}, AllSheets, {"RefId"}, "AllSheets", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded AllSheets" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "AllSheets", {"Component"}, {"AllSheets.Component"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded AllSheets",{{"Master Component", type text}}),
    dupsNull = List.Generate(
        ()=>[v=#"Changed Type"[Master Component]{0}, idx=0],
        each [idx]<Table.RowCount(#"Changed Type"),
        each [v=if List.PositionOf(#"Changed Type"[Master Component],#"Changed Type"[Master Component]{[idx]+1},Occurrence.First) = [idx]+1
                    then #"Changed Type"[Master Component]{[idx]+1} else null, idx=[idx]+1],
        each [v]),
    #"add de-duped" = Table.FromColumns(
            Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") & {dupsNull},
            type table[Id=text, Master Component=text, AllSheets.Component=text,Master Component.unique=text]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"add de-duped",{"Master Component"}),
    ConcatComponents = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Components", each Text.Combine({[Master Component.unique],Text.From([AllSheets.Component])},",")),
    RemovedComponents = Table.RemoveColumns(ConcatComponents,{"AllSheets.Component", "Master Component.unique"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(RemovedComponents, {"Id"}, {{"Components", each Text.Combine([Components], ","), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks for the detailed step-by-step explanation! Sorry for the late accept, took me some time to wrap my head around PQ and sort out some details, but it works now. ^^